# How to mock FormGroup's get method, without using TestBeds?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, spy

I have a component, I have declared one of its property as `groupForm : FormGroup`. In one of the method I am getting value of a form field and assigning it to a constant like:

```js
const value = this.groupForm.get('field').value;
```

Later I am using this constant to check one condition and do something like:

```js
if (value.$type === 'Variable') {
    // do something
}
```

In the component's **.spec.ts** file, I am writing the unit test case using Jasmin and Karma, I am trying to mock this like:

```js
let groupFormMock = spyOn(component.groupForm, 'get')
groupFormMock.and.returnValues({
    value: {
        $type: "Variable",
        name: "Variable",
        variableType: "Text",
        description: "Variable",
        category: "Actions",
        subCategory: "Variable",
        initialValue: "Test",
        sortOrder: 0
    }
})
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Argument of type '{ value: { $type: string; name: string; variableType: string; description: string; category: string; subCategory: string; initialValue: string; sortOrder: number; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AbstractControl'.
  Type '{ value: { $type: string; name: string; variableType: string; description: string; category: string; subCategory: string; initialValue: string; sortOrder: number; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'AbstractControl': validator, asyncValidator, _parent, _asyncValidationSubscription, and 43 more.
```

So, I thought, consoling the value of `JSON.stringify(this.groupForm.get('variableName'))` and returning this as mock object would solve the problem, but this gave me another error:

```
An error occurred: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Subscriber'
    |     property '_subscriptions' -> object with constructor 'Array'
    |     index 0 -> object with constructor 'SubjectSubscription'
    --- property '_parentOrParents' closes the circle
```

The object returned by the `get` method, is a circular object (object referencing themselves), which can't be consoled. So, I need to create a mock object of AbstractControl, so that I can use this and return it in the mock method. Or, any solutions to solve this problem are welcomed.

I am stuck, any leads would be helpful.

P.S. : I need do this with out using TestBeds.

Comment: What about instantiating  a `FormGroup` using `FormBuilder` and return it?

Comment: OK, will try that and let you know.

Comment: Thanks, @Eldar. Your solution gave an idea. I created an objected `formGroupMock` of `FormGroup`, pached the values like `formGroupMock.patchValues()` and it worked.

Comment: Would you like to post it as answer and I can accept it?

Comment: No need for it, glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **.spec.ts** file, declare the mock objects like:

```
let formGroupMock: FormGroup;
let formBuilderMock: any;
```

Initialize the objects and  mock the `FormBuilder`'s `group()` method call like:

```
formGroupMock = new FormGroup({
    field : new FormControl()
});
formBuilderMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('FormBuilder', ['group']);
formBuilderMock.group.and.returnValue(formGroupMock);
```

Patch the values to the form like:

```js
formGroup.patchValue({
    field : {
        $type: "Variable",
        name: "Variable",
        variableType: "Text",
        description: "Variable",
        category: "Actions",
        subCategory: "Variable",
        initialValue: "Test",
        sortOrder: 0
    }
});
```